# jVectorMap define data series on the fly

Tags: jvectormap

What I am trying to do and is failing is this:

```
worldMap.series.regions[0]=new jvm.DataSeries({
    scale:['#CCCCCC','#FF0000'],
    normalizeFunction:'polynomial',
    values:{'country_code':value...},
    min:minValue,
    max:maxValue
});
```

The error I get is that regions is not defined, so I'm doing that wrong.
What is the proper way of doing that and how can I dispose of data if I don't need it anymore (as in remove colouring of countries as if map was initialized with empty dataset).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to change series data then you can use `DataSeries` methods like `clear` and `setValues`:

```
worldMap.series.regions[0].clear();
```

Comment: Hello. `setValues()` does not work because my the `min` and `max` change as well as the `scale` array of colours. I tried using `setAttribute()` for modifying the `min` and `max` values, but that failed. Basically, when the data changes and I want to show new data, all countries get a new colour.

Comment: In your GDP slider example, I saw that you get around this by instantiating the map div on each AJAX success callback, `new jvm.WorldMap(...)`, but I was hoping there's a better way than making the same settings each time just to change `values`, `scale`, `min` and `max`.

Comment: After more experimenting, what I need is to be able to change min and max after each request to the server for data. Is that possible?

Comment: You can try map.series.regions[0].scale.setMin/setMax and then reset values for the series. Not sure about the result though.

Comment: From what I could see, setting them after map was drawn doesn't work. Why did you use `setMin` and `setMax`? Did you mean `.min` and `.max`? Thank you.